# regex to remove special characters in mule3

Tags: mule, mulesoft

I am getting some inputs in Mule3 and all have some special characters.

examples of input string is as below:

```
 "@不mule@#soft还!#%%"
```

I need to remove all special characters and need only "mulesoft" as string in output (or you can say only alphanumeric characters from string)

I have researched some regex but didn't get any luck

Comment: I think that you mean that the output should only contain alphabetic (or alphanumeric?) characters. Otherwise ignoring the input and have the output be a fixed string "mulesoft" would be a valid answer.

Comment: Aled, you are right i need output with all alphanumeric characters, i just gave an examples that if string comes like this ("@不mule@#soft还!#%%") then output should be "mulesoft".  i have edited the question now .Thanks

Comment: Aled,I have received two answers below and in which you said scan is not good option so should I use replace, is it good to go with answer that is using replace? please help

Comment: Both are valid, I just believe that using replace is a bit more clear and direct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another way of getting desired output

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
%var text = "@不s/\p@#ecial还!#%%"
---
"output": text replace /([^0-9a-zA-Z]+)/ with ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [scan](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/1.2/dataweave-operators#scan)

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
flatten("@不mule@#soft还!#%%" scan /[a-zA-Z]/) joinBy ""
```

Comment: This solution will work but using scan() is unnecessary to work with regex.

Comment: Thank you @aled . I will be more cautious ,but can you please elaborate why is it not unnecessary to use scan with regex? I noticed in the documentation itself they have used scan with regex

Comment: scan returns an array of matches, then you join it back into a string. replace returns the modified string directly. scans requires an extra conversion to arrays. Hence I believe using replace is a little more direct and clear solution.